# Analyze window dump log from Android

Tags: android

I have just made a window dump to my adb emulator using

```
adb shell su -- dumpsys window
```

And I obtain:

```
Window #1 Window{b24be838 u0
com.honda.res/com.foo.res.sources.SourcesActivity}:
mDisplayId=0 mSession=Session{b1f70070 1711:u0a10044} mClient=android.os.BinderProxy@b21c6a78
mOwnerUid=10044 mShowToOwnerOnly=true package=com.foo.res appop=NONE
mAttrs=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#10 ty=1 fl=#1810100 pfl=0x8 wanim=0x10302b3}
Requested w=1280 h=800 mLayoutSeq=130
mHasSurface=true mShownFrame=[0.0,0.0][1280.0,800.0] isReadyForDisplay()=true
WindowStateAnimator{b243bd18 com.foo.res/com.foo.res.sources.SourcesActivity}:
Surface: shown=true layer=21005 alpha=1.0 rect=(0.0,0.0) 1280.0 x 800.0
```

I want to know where the layer number comes from `layer=21005` (line 9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong, but *Layer 21005* stands for a unique number assigned for each layer of your Android application, which depends on kernel, libraries, system applications and so on.

Here is an example of Android layers:

[image]